# Dynamic Select Choice using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two choice boxes as follows,

```
<select name="first" id="first">
   <option value="0">First</option>
   <option value="1">Second</option>
   <option value="2">Third</option>
   <option value="3">Fourth</option>
   <option value="4">Five</option>
   <option value="5">Six</option>
   <option value="6">Seven</option>
</select>
```

Second Select box :

```
<select name="first" id="first">
   <option value="0">First</option>
   <option value="1">Second</option>
   <option value="2">Third</option>
   <option value="3">Fourth</option>
   <option value="4">Five</option>
   <option value="5">Six</option>
   <option value="6">Seven</option>
</select>
```

Now when I select "First" in first select box at that time I should not able to select First choice in second select box. If I select second in first choice then  I should not able to select 1st and second from second list box, if third then I should not able to select first, second and third. So on..  How can I do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: And the first, second and the third are selected at the same time in the first select?

Comment: If we select third in first option, should 1 to 3 appear in second option or they should not be in list?

Comment: the ID of the second is second I assume?

Comment: Adding the code you got so far will help in getting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first give a different name and id to the second select (second for example) and try this JS:

```
$('#first').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $('#second').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() <= value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled',false)
        }
    });

    $('#second').val(parseInt(value)+1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlesrv/av97qfqc/2/

Comment: Thanks man !!! What does this website(http://jsfiddle.net/) do ? Because I'm newbie :)

Comment: It can be use as an online editor to test some HTML/CSS/JS code and save it as well

Comment: jsFiddle is a way to quickly test javascript, html, and css in your browser without making a file and all of that hassle.

Comment: Another help! When I select first, second's value should not stay first it should be changed to second, If 2nd element is selected then 1st and 2nd should be disabled and second's value must be changed to Three!

Comment: If I select last one. The second select box gets empty! I tried but didnt work!

Comment: What should happen in that case?

Comment: Last should remain as last! And can you suggest me any tutorials which can help me to learn JQuery ?

Comment: I mean If in first select is selected the last element in second select should be selected the last one too? (like an exception to the other ones)

Answer (score 0):

I did it without jQuery:

HTML:

```
<select name="first" id="first" onchange="changed()">
   <option value="0">First</option>
   <option value="1">Second</option>
   <option value="2">Third</option>
   <option value="3">Fourth</option>
   <option value="4">Five</option>
   <option value="5">Six</option>
   <option value="6">Seven</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second">
   <option value="0">First</option>
   <option value="1">Second</option>
   <option value="2">Third</option>
   <option value="3">Fourth</option>
   <option value="4">Five</option>
   <option value="5">Six</option>
   <option value="6">Seven</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function changed() {
    var selected = document.getElementById("first").selectedIndex;
    for( var i=0; i<=document.getElementById("second").options.length; i++ ) {
        document.getElementById( "second" ).options[i].disabled = false;
    }
    for( var i=0; i<=selected; i++ ) {
        document.getElementById( "second" ).options[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `id` of second select. Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vLh27zn/1/)

The value in second select should change with value select in first box:

```
$("#first").on("change",function(){
     var selected = $(this).val();
$('#second').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() <= selected ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled',false)
        }
    });
   $('#second').val(parseInt(selected)+1) //To change value in second select
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#first').change(function() {
    var v = $(this).find("option:selected").index();

    $('select[id!="first"] option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).index() <= v ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled',false)
        }
    });           

});
```

Try this code,this does not need to you to add any new `ID` or `names`.

Comment: @John btw you rule is kind of weird,if i select the last option in the first select,then nothing can be selected in the second?

Comment: Because of this : csgoboost.com/rank-boost/